# How to add value " in file gradle for android?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle

In file app.gradle, i define a value as below:

```
buildConfigField "String", "AS_ABC", "\"ABC\".XYZ\""
```

however when i run app i got error "error: unclosed string literal". because gradle compile to value

```
public static final String AS_ABC= "ABC".XYZ";
```

How to add character " in value file app.gradle?

Comment: i updated to "\"ABC\\\".XYZ\"" and it's work